# Update Binding Items Upload Collection

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to use a UploadCollection in my SAPUI5 App, to upload files and display them to the user. My page has two UploadCollections. One to upload and display PDF-Documents and one for JPG-Image files. The upload via a Odata V2 Service works perfectly well, but I ran into a difficulty displaying the uploaded files in the correct UploadCollection.

After the successful Upload of all files in both UploadCollections I'm triggering a refresh on the binding Items of both Upload Collections. Sadly this refresh is ignoring the filters which are applied to the items of each UploadCollection. This leads to the unfortunate situation, that the pdf and image files are displayed in both UploadCollections and not only in the correct Image- or PDF-UploadCollection. I would love to know why this is the case.

I've already tried to filter the binding items again, but then the request magically remembers that there has been a filter applied to the UploadCollection items from the beginning and therefore is executed with the same filter applied two times which leads to an error.

The only solution I found this far is to completely reload the page to reapply the correct filter to each Upload Collection. It would be fantastic if someone could help me with issue and possibly supply any solutions.

UploadColelction items Binding:

**UC1**: *items="{path:'ImageSet', filters:[{path: 'Filetype', operator: 'EQ' , value1: 'IBR'}]}"*

**UC2**: *items="{path:'ImageSet', filters:[{path: 'Filetype', operator: 'EQ' , value1: 'DBR'}]}"*

Comment: Why are both UploadCollections bound to the same EntitySet? Maybe you need two EntitySets (a PDF is not an Image)? Maybe you need only one UploadCollection?

Comment: Thanks for your input. The EntitySet is not the problem, nor are the UploadCollections. Everything works as excpected besids the getBinding("items").refresh() function for the Upload Collections. The two Upload Collections are not excplicity required but are just a bit more user friendly.

Comment: Well if you had two different EntitySets for Images and PDFs there would be no filters. I cannot tell you the reason why the Collections show the same items and forget to filter but I'd guess that two EntitySets would solve your problem.

Comment: i hade a same issue but with a diffrent controll. but what for me helps instead of reload the page is to make a new function and read agean the service and refresh the model

Comment: Yeah, you're right Marc, it wouldn't solve the problem itself, but would be a good workaround which no user would notice the difference of.